# Arrays.asList: when a set is used as the argument we get back a list<set<Integer>> instead of List<Integer>

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
Set<Integer> iset = new HashSet<>();
iset.add(1);
List<Integer> ilist =  Arrays.asList(iset);
```

My intention was to convert the set of integers into a list of integers but the compiler complains that a List> cannot be converted to a List. Why does asList work this way and when would one use it? What is the correct way to convert a Set to List?

Comment: `List<Integer> ilist =  new ArrayList<>(iset);`

Comment: You do asList(oneX), and you get a List of OneX ... there is no auto "unpacking" of that set object!

Answer (score 10):

Because `Arrays.asList` treats `iset` as only one element. That's why this creates `List<Set<Integer>>`.

To make a list of the elements in a set, pass the set to the constructor of the list.

```
List<Integer> ilist = new ArrayList<Integer>(iset);
```

Different uses of [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
List<Integer> ilist1 = Arrays.asList(1); // Single element
List<Integer> ilist2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3); // Multiple element
Integer a[] = new Integer[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 }; 
List<Integer> ilist3 = Arrays.asList(a); // Array
```

Comment: so the normal usage of the method is to provide it with multiple arguments?

Comment: The normal usage of `Arrays.asList` is to provide it with an **array of things**, which can mean either a single `thing[]` argument, or multiple `thing` arguments.  Either way, you get back a `List<thing>`.

Comment: You can use array or single element both

Comment: That's called *varargs*.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following example can help you to understand why this is happening.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class practice {

    public static void main(String... string) {


        /**
         *  This will return a list of Integer, because if we see the implementation of Arrays.asList() 
         *  then this all puzzle will be solved.
         *  Arrays can process a Array collection of data.
         *  asList is generic implementation, returned object data type will be same as received dataType                     
         */
        Integer a[] = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
        List<Integer> arrList =  Arrays.asList(a);


        /**
         * But in this case, Arrays.asList() is receiving a collection of Integer object and asList will try to return the 
         * same type of data as it received.
         * So it received Set and will return set 
         * and for more investigation apply debug points in ArrayList class under java.util.Arrays.ArrayList  
         */
        Set<Integer> iset = new HashSet<>();
        iset.add(1);
        List<Set<Integer>> ilist =  Arrays.asList(iset);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList` receives a *varargs* argument, which is an array under the covers.

It simply returns a `List` object that contains the elements of the array argument.

So, if you do:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

You get a `List<Integer>` containing `[1, 2, 3]`.

If you have this generic class:

```
class MyObject<T> { }
```

And do:

```
MyObject<String> myStrObj1 = new MyObject<>();
MyObject<String> myStrObj2 = new MyObject<>();

List<MyObject<String>> myStrObjects = Arrays.asList(myStrObj1, myStrObj2);
```

You get a `List<MyObject<String>>` containing `[myStrObj1, myStrObj2]`.

The same happens when you pass some instances of `Set<Integer>` to `Arrays.asList`:

```
Set<Integer> integerSet1 = new HashSet<>();
integerSet1.add(1);

Set<Integer> integerSet2 = new HashSet<>();
integerSet2.add(5);
integerSet2.add(6);

List<Set<Integer>> integerSets =  Arrays.asList(integerSet1, integerSet2);
```

You get a `List<Set<Integers>>` containing `[[1], [5, 6]]`.

---

If you just want to create a new `List` object with the same elements as the `Set` object, you have to iterate the set and add each one of its elements to the list:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);
set.add(3);

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (Integer element : set) {
    list.add(element);
}
```

Luckily, the constructor of `ArrayList` does exactly this for you. So all you have to do is:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);
set.add(3);

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
```